# How can you set an enumerate counter which contains both letters and numbers?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am including, using the `enumerate` environment, some sections from legislation.

In legislation, it is common to indicate subsections which were added later through the use of letters.  So, for example, we might have:

```
5    Awesome section

(1)  This subsection existed from the beginning.
(1A) This subsection was inserted later.
(2)  And we continue with the original Act
```

I'm having trouble inserting '(1A)' as an enumerate counter.

When I use the `enumerate` package, and do:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1A)]
```

the package appears to treat 'A' as the counter, and outputs '(AA)'.

When I try to use `setcounter`, as in:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{1A}
```

I get

```
! Package calc Error: `A' invalid at this point.
```

How can I insert `(1A)`, or similar letter number combinations, as an enumerate counter?

I'm not awfully fussed that it actually *count* correctly; I'm just after identical formatting to a normal `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Is `1A` not rather a sub-enumerate environment, although one should not use lists with just one entry. If there are more of them however, I would use `\begin{enumerate}` again to indicate the additions, with some redefined counter `enumii`

Comment: You can not use `setcounter{enumi}{1A} with a non number argument. And it is `\labelenumi` you have to change

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after posting my question, I realised the answer: use the optional argument to `\item`.

In other words:

```
\item[(1A)] This subsection was inserted later.
```

Answer (score 2):

This introduces a command `\addeditem` which uses `itemtopnumber itemsubletter`, i.e. `1A 1B` etc. if necessary, however there is some 'bug' that the counter is not correctly advanced, I try to figure out why, so that one has to reset it manually at the moment.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\newcounter{itemadded}
\setcounter{itemadded}{0}


\newcommand{\addeditem}{%
\addtocounter{enumi}{-1}%
\stepcounter{itemadded}
\let\LaTeXStandardLabelEnumi\labelenumi%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{(\arabic{enumi}\Alph{itemadded})}}%
\item 
% Switch back to old labelling 
\let\labelenumi\LaTeXStandardLabelEnumi%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardEnumerateBegin\enumerate
\let\LaTeXStandardEnumerateEnd\endenumerate

\renewenvironment{enumerate}{%
\LaTeXStandardEnumerateBegin%
\setcounter{itemadded}{0}
}{%
\LaTeXStandardEnumerateEnd%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\addeditem First added
\addeditem Second added
\item Next item 
\item Third item \setcounter{itemadded}{0}
\addeditem Another subitem added
\end{enumerate}


\begin{center}
\huge Just a repeat without resetting \texttt{itemadded}
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\addeditem First added
\addeditem Second added
\item Next item 
\item Third item
\addeditem Another subitem added
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know, that I have to write `\newcounter{itemadded}[enumi]` and `\refstepcounter{itemadded}` but it does not work->>> Why?